# Как правильно добавлять/обновлять/удалять данные?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть 2 варианта решения по CUD (CRUD):

- меньше запросов;
- более объектно-ориентированно.

Какой будет более предпочтительней при "правильной" разработке?

```
//Вариант с меньшим количеством запросов к БД

class ArticleService
{
  public functon update($id, $request){
    $data = $request->only('text','title')
    $this->repository->updateById($id, $data);
  }
  public functon delete($id){
    $this->repository->deleteById($id;
  }
  public functon create($request){
    $data = $request->only('text','title')
    $this->repository->add($data);
  }
}

//Вариант более объектно-ориентированный

class ArticleService
{
  public functon update($id, $request){
    $article = $this->repository->get($id);
    $article->title = $request->input('title');
    $article->text = $request->input('text');
    $this->repository->update($article);
  }

  public functon delete($id){
    $article = $this->repository->get($id);
    $this->repository->delete($article);
  }
  public functon create($request){
    $article = new Article();
    $article->title = $request->input('title');
    $article->text = $request->input('text');
    $this->repository->add($article);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Какой будет более предпочтительней при "правильной" разработке?

**предпочтительней** будет второй.

**Правильный** будет читать доку по используемому инструменту ([Laravel 5.5 CRUD Tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2017/10/15/laravel-5-5-crud-example-tutorial/))
и следовать код стайлу самого фреймворка.

Comment: Если по код стайлу фреймворка писать - то все писать в контроллерах, а по данной ссылке и валидация в них. Что такое себе... 
Если погуглить по поводу репозиториев для Ларавел - то многие пишут именно про первый вариант. Поэтому вопрос и был задан.  Ссылка 1
https://www.larashout.com/how-to-use-repository-pattern-in-laravel
Ссылка 2 
https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce